# Image under Möbius transformation

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis

I would like to find the image of

$$ {z \in C: |z|<1, Im{z}>0 } $$

under the complex map

$$ w(z) = \frac{2z-i}{iz+2} $$.

Well, since $w(2i)=\infty$ the interval $[-1,1]$ and $ {z \in C: |z|=1, Im{z}>0 } $
are mapped to circles, say $C_1$ and $C_2$ connecting

$$w_1=w(-1)=-\frac{3}{5} -\frac{4}{5}i$$
$$w_2=w(1) = \frac{3}{5} -\frac{4}{5}i$$

My problem is how to find the centers of $C_1$ and $C_2$ correspondingly. I know that the Möbius map preserves the inverse points, and this information should help me find the centers. For instance $2i$ and $-2i$ are symmetric with respect to the real line and $2i$ and $i/2$ are symmetric with respect to $|z|=1$. Unfortunately I don't see how this information will help me find the centers of $C_1$ and $C_2$.

From the answers I konw that I should get unit circle and $|z+\frac{5i}{4}|=\frac{3}{4}$

Your help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The image of $ \{|z|<1 \}$ is determined by $w_1, w_2$ and $w(i) = i$.

The image of $\{\text{Im } z > 0\}$ is determined by $w_1, w_2$ and $w(\infty)
= -2i$.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your reply. My problem is actually to see how by knowing, that $w(-2i)=-\frac{-5i}{4}$ I get the cneter of $C_2$ is located at $-\frac{-5i}{4}$ and the radius is $\frac{3}{4}$. The same holds for the first circle $C_1$, where $w(\frac{i}{2})=0$ and we can conclude that the image is the unit disk centered at the origin.

Comment: @AlexanderCska: $-2i$ and $2i$ are symmetric with respect to the real axis, therefore $w(-2i)=-5i/4$ and $w(2i) = \infty$ are "symmetric" with respect to $C_2$. On the other hand, the center of a circle is symmetric to $\infty$ with respect to that circle. Is that what you are looking for?

Comment: Yes precisely! So it turns out that my image is $|w|<1 / |z+\frac{5i}{4}|<\frac{3}{4} $. Just in an attempt to understand the general principle. Here we have no singularities, but what would happen if we had one. For instance, the image of $Rez>0 Imz>0$ under  $w(z) = \frac{z-i}{z+1}$. This should map to the part of the the unit disk located in the upper half plane. Since $w(-i)=\infty$, the ray $[i0,i\infty]$ should map $[-1,1]$. Is this correct? Thank you for the help!

Comment: @AlexanderCska: You are thinking too complicated. $(z-i)/(z+i)$ maps the imaginary axis onto the real axis, and $0, i, \infty$ to $-1, 0, 1$.

Comment: I decided to ask this, because it sounds counterintuitive to me that $[i0,i\infty]$ is mapped not to a circle. i.e. $-i \notin [i0,i\infty]$ but it still affects the map. It is as if the entire imaginary axis should be considered, although we are interested in only the part $[i0,i\infty]$.

Comment: @AlexanderCska: Möbius transforms map circles and (extended) lines to circles or (extended) lines, therefore it is always useful to consider a line segment as part of an entire line. Whether the image is a circle or line depends only on if the image contains infinity or not. – If you consider lines as "special circles through infinity" then it becomes even easier: circles are mapped to circles.

Comment: Sorry! But i would be grateful if you can answer my question: i understood that center of circle at $-5i/4$. If $\infty$ and it center are symmetric how to find radius of circle?

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Find the inverse $w^{-1}$ and use the fact that $(w^{-1} )^{-1} (A)=w(A).$

Comment: Yeah, that's not helpful. The algebra is atrocious.